# Why do I get error 'unrecognized command line option '-fuse-ld=--enable-gold=default' when building Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to build Tensorflow from source as described at: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source

I have Bazel 0.29.1 and Python available. I do:

```
module load bazeltest/0.29.1
module load pythontest/gcc6.3.0/3.7.5tensorflow
./configure
```

I choose all default options in configure, then:

```
bazel build //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

The build proceeds for a while, but fails at:

```
INFO: Analyzed target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /gpfs01/home/cczcb/.cache/bazel/_bazel_cczcb/f0a4604cf88277481621943e2a61f102/external/swig/BUILD.bazel:5:1: Linking of rule '@swig//:swig' failed (Exit 1)
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-fuse-ld=--enable-gold=default'
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 18.642s, Critical Path: 10.57s
INFO: 125 processes: 125 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

I have also tried:

```
bazel build --cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

as I am using GCC 6.3.0 here.  The result is the same, as it is when I use GCC 4.9.3.
My O/S is Centos 7.4.

Can anyone advise what might be amiss ?
thanks,
Colin